# SBT cannot find bash while creating a Scala seed project in Play 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, window, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to create a new scala seed project in Play 2.6. From play's website I can see that they dropped the use of activator and switched to sbt commands.

I'm getting a "bash" file not found message (see below), even though I'm running SBT on Windows. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I installed SBT version 1.0.4.

```
C:\test>sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
"C:\Users\pablo\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/C:/test/)
10:29:52.037 [main] ERROR org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS - Caught exception in FS.readPipe()
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\pablo"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.readPipe(FS.java:431) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.discoverGitPrefix(FS_Win32.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.gitPrefix(FS.java:517) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader$Default.openSystemConfig(SystemReader.java:92) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:171) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:577) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.init(CloneCommand.java:161) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:132) ~[?:?]
        at giter8.JgitHelper$.clone(JgitHelper.scala:116) ~[?:?]
        at giter8.JgitHelper$.run(JgitHelper.scala:67) ~[?:?]
        at giter8.JgitHelper$.run(JgitHelper.scala:80) ~[?:?]
        at giter8.Giter8.$anonfun$run$2(giter8.scala:34) ~[?:?]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library.jar:1.0.2]
        at giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:33) ~[?:?]
        at sbtgiter8resolver.Giter8TemplateResolver.run(Giter8TemplateResolver.scala:31) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.call(TemplateCommand.scala:93) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:71) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1(TemplateCommand.scala:51) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(TemplateCommand.scala:47) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111) ~[scala-library.jar:1.0.2]
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:108) ~[scala-library.jar:1.0.2]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.find(List.scala:86) ~[scala-library.jar:1.0.2]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.run(TemplateCommand.scala:47) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:34) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$templateCommand$2(TemplateCommand.scala:17) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:125) ~[command_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:121) ~[command_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:121) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:105) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:227) ~[command_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:233) ~[command_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:105) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16) ~[util-control_2.12-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:105) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:98) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:76) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22) ~[io_2.12-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:70) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:52) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:37) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:29) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:104) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:71) ~[main_2.12-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17) ~[?:?]
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        ... 59 more
```

Comment: Is this the same issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7768

Comment: Looks like a git bash problem.Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933412/while-creating-new-project-java-project-with-play-using-sbt-new-playframework-p/47649578#47649578.

Comment: Looks like a git bash problem. Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933412/while-creating-new-project-java-project-with-play-using-sbt-new-playframework-p/47649578#47649578.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you need to to use sbt.bat instead of sbt (which is for *nix systems).

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7768

Also as mentionned in this issue, please try to add the certificate of https://dl.bintray.com/ to the java keystore. The java keystore location is the cacerts file inside `jdk_version\jre\security\`

Comment: running `sbt.bat` instead of `sbt` produces exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pretty much old problem: this is because there is no *git bash* installed on your local. 
Once you install git (see [installer here](https://git-scm.com/download/win)) this will error disappear.

Answer (score -1):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7768), you need to use `sbt.bat` in Windows:

```
sbt.bat new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```